# Persisting data across the app through global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-3.5, global-asax

I need to store a globally accessible list in my C#/ASP project - Storing it in the global app on the server instead of the database - as the data is only needed when the app is running.

So far I have tried to create a list in the application start (Global Asax)
`activePages= new List<ActivePage>(); Session["activePages"] = activePages;`

Which obviously fails as I cant set the Session at this point. What is the correct way?

Ideally, I want to be able to set up a blank list when the App starts, and add to the list from any session (i.e. I could add to this list from my PC and Laptop at the same time)

I already have the code to do all the adding and management, but cant find a way to globally persist this list. Also, How would I then use this list on other pages in my app? I've not really had to touch the global asax before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to have a look at [Application State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178594.aspx). Using the `Session` will no solve your problems as for each user visiting your application, a new session will be created. Also, after some time of inactivity `Session` is destroyed.

```
   void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
   {
        List<ActivePage> activePages= new List<ActivePage>();
        Application["ActivePages"] = activePages;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access the data from anywhere, you can define a static variable. Than on the start of the application you can load the data into this variable:

```
public static List<ActivePage> ActivePages= new List<ActivePage>();

protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ActivePages = LoadFromDB()
}
```

You can also add values to this list at anytime from anywhere, as the variable is static.

However - what you want to do with the data later? When IIS will be restarted, than all the content of this list will be lost.

You can not use the Session for this kind of global storage.